# How do you pre-set values on the right-hand side of a Shuttle Item in Oracle APEX?

Tags: textbox, default, oracle-apex

I've looked at numerous forums and tutorials, but it doesn't display the values on the right hand side of the

shuttle. However, if I look at the Session values, it seems to set the values properly, it just doesn't show it

in the Shuttle Item itself.
I've done exactly what I found here:
http://dgielis.blogspot.com/2008/01/apex-by-example-default-value-of.html
http://kr.forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=855688

But none of them are working for me. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it turns out that everything is working properly behind the scenes, as indicated in the Session values when I check them.
The only other thing I needed to do was go to the Shuttle properties -> LOV -> Set 'Display Extra Values' to YES.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to preset the values A, B and D on the right hand side of a shuttle item, set the Default property of the item to

```
A:B:D
```